# Design pattern for creating, inserting and updating a domain object

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, design-patterns

I have gotten into a design issue with my current code base, and I cant decide which pattern I should follow in order to create and maintain a complex object.

The flow of my application can be outlined in a series of steps:

1. Consume and parse message from AMQP-broker
2. Create base of complex object with parsed data
3. Insert object to database
4. Update complex object by a series of steps and rules
5. Update object in database

Right now I am utilizing the builder-pattern but it doesent feel right? I need some sort of pattern that handles the creation of the object and that can also maintain the object by using a service layer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unit of Work + Visitor? If you're already using NHibernate then that covers unit of work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not unit of work i'm looking for. I'm looking for a pattern that can manage the object creation and the updating in a nice way.

Comment: I don't know if there is a "ready to bake" - pattern. Maybe rather a combination of different patterns. Patterns are great, but don't apply in any concern of software development. Since you mentioned "object creation" in your comment above: There you might look into factory-pattern.